# C# - How would I shorten my code?

Tags: c#

This program converts the users input from either inches, feet, or yards and converts it to either inches, feet, or yards. It works with 100% efficiency and, from my testing, it has no errors. If you find any I apologize.

My question is, since this is very lengthy piece of code for something so simple. Is there a more simple way of writing this? A friend of mine is working on the same problem and he is dead set that there is a more simple way.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Declared inches, feet, and yards a global variable.
    public double feet;
    public double inches;
    public double yards;

    private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declared a variable for an the originlalDistanceInput
        double distanceInput;

        // Checks to make sure that the user didn't input a letter. If so return an error message.
        if (!double.TryParse(originalDistanceInput.Text, out distanceInput) || distanceInput < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an a number greater than 0 and not a letter.", "Notice");
            originalDistanceInput.Clear();
        }

        else
        {
            if (fromList.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a conversion input.");
            }

            else if (toList.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a conversion output.");
            }

            // Checks the listbox to make sure that the
            else if (fromList.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string from = fromList.SelectedItem.ToString();

                switch (from)
                {
                    case "Inches":
                        if (toList.SelectedIndex == 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You did not make a conversion!", "Notice");
                            originalDistanceInput.Clear();
                        }

                        else if (toList.SelectedIndex == 1)
                        {
                            feet = distanceInput / 12;
                            convertedOutput.Text = feet.ToString("##.#### 'FT'");
                        }

                        else if (toList.SelectedIndex == 2)
                        {
                            yards = distanceInput / 36;
                            convertedOutput.Text = yards.ToString("##.#### 'YD'");
                        }
                        break;



                    case "Feet":
                        if (toList.SelectedIndex == 0)
                        {
                            inches = distanceInput * 12;
                            convertedOutput.Text = inches.ToString("##.#### 'IN'");
                        }

                        else if (toList.SelectedIndex == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You did not make a converstion!", "Notice");
                            originalDistanceInput.Clear();
                        }

                        else if (toList.SelectedIndex == 2)
                        {
                            yards = distanceInput / 3;
                            convertedOutput.Text = yards.ToString("##.#### 'YD'");
                        }
                        break;

                    case "Yards":
                        if (toList.SelectedIndex == 0)
                        {
                            inches = distanceInput * 36;
                            convertedOutput.Text = inches.ToString("##.#### 'IN'");
                        }

                        else if (toList.SelectedIndex == 1)
                        {
                            feet = distanceInput * 3;
                            convertedOutput.Text = feet.ToString("##.#### 'FT'");
                        }

                        else if (toList.SelectedIndex == 2)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You did not make a converstion!", "Notice");
                            originalDistanceInput.Clear();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me; is this a homework question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Crud! I didn't know there was such a thing. Thank you!

Comment: short is not always better, see code golf, http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Claies it is not a homework problem.

Comment: @BryanOlesky Check http://kl1p.com/03kW for a code review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would convert everything to a standard unit, then convert this back into the output units. This will allow it to be far more extensible in the end. The same conversion factors could be used in reverse to get the output unit. In fact, if you can do it, make an object that has the name of the unit, conversion to the standard reference (I would use metric units, as they are the most standard), and anything else you need. For instance, you could create a class units (Proto code, I'm not a C# guru yet...)

```
class Unit {
   private float convertToStandard;
   private string unitName;

   Unit(float conversionFactor, string unitName) {
      convertToStandard=coversionFactor;
      this.unitName=unitName;
   }
}
```

You could then do a lot of things, like add in a covert function to change it to different units, taking in a unit function. This Unit function, while it might add a few lines of code, will be much cleaner overall, and will allow you to add new units with only a few extra calls. Thus, adding new units becomes very simple:

```
new Unit (1,"meter");
new Unit (0.3048,"feet");
```

Add a convert function, and it's even easier. The convert function could look like this (Inside the Unit class):

```
public float convertToThisUnit(Unit from) {
    return from.convertToStandard/this.convertToStandard; 
}
```

You could keep going, but the bottom line is, unit conversion should take some sort of an object oriented approach, which will make it far simpler, although it might add a few lines of code for such a short example as what you have here.

Comment: but would it make the code shorter?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: I would do the same suggestion. And moreover, I'd also use constants to handle conversion instead of hardcoded numbers everywhere.

Comment: It should make the code shorter. I'm working on elaborating, hang in there...

Comment: @BryanOlesky He's saying to convert everything to one single unit. Then convert that unit to whatever the output is. Consider inches, feet and yards as I, F, and Y. You currently have code for II, IF, IY, FI, FF, FY, YI, YF, YY. So first step - check if input and output are the same and show that message ONE time. You have it three times now. Next, always convert to one thing - say Feet. Then convert out. Now your conversion code is IF, YF. Your ouput conversion is FI, FY. Much simpler and shorter.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around both of your variations @Paul and PearsonArtPhoto